# Get data from two collections in loop using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to make search api. From request body location search the user. For that I need data from two collections i.e. user collection and sessionSlot collection. From user collection want fullname, profilepic, location, mail, etc. and from user's _id want data from sessionSlot collection.

I tried following code:

```js
var register = mongoose.model("user");
var sessionSlot = mongoose.model("sessionSlot");

register.find({
          'location.address': {
            $regex: '^' + req.body.address,
            $options: 'i'
          },
        }]
      }).exec(function (err, userDetail) {
        for (var i = 0; i < userDetail.length; i++) {

          sessionSlot.findOne({
            'userID': userDetail[i]._id
          }).exec(function (err1, slotData) {
            if(slotData) {
              if(slotData.sessions.length > 0) {
                async.eachSeries(slotData.sessions, (slots, callback) => {
                  if (req.body.date) {
                    if (moment(slots.date).isSame(moment(req.body.date), 'day')) {
                      // console.log('slots--->', slots);                  
                      sessionData.push({
                        time: slots.time,
                        status: slots.status,
                        slotID: slotData.slotID,
                      });
                    }
                  }
                  else {
                    sessionData.push({
                      time: slots.time,
                      status: slots.status,
                      slotID: slotData.slotID,
                    });
                  }
                  slotCnt++;
                  callback();
                });
              }
            }
            else {
              console.log('no slot created..',slotData);
              sessionData = [];
            }
           })
        }
        res.json({'code':200, 'data':sessionData})
      })
```

I am not getting proper response from the sessionSlot collection, sometimes it is overwritten data or sometimes null (like taking last value from array).

Please give me suggestion!!

I am using mongoose version 4.5 (Not using aggregate)

```js
user schema: 
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
   fullname:   { type: String, default: null },
   mail :   { type: String, default: null },
   profilepic :   { type: String, default: null },
})

sessionSlot schema:
var sessionSlotSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    userID      : { type: String },
    mail        : { type: String },
    slotID      : { type: String },
    slotFlag    : { type: Boolean },
    sessions    : [{
                    status       : { type: String, default:'empty' },
                    profilepic   : { type: String, default:null },
                    fullname     : { type: String, default:null },
                    autoBook     : { type: Boolean, default:false },
                    time         : { type: String, default: null }
    }]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code it seems that the issue is with the way you are trying to load sessionSlots, so once you get all users you are using simple for loop (synchronous code) to load sessionSlots of each user (which is asynchronous) so maybe try to use async each there

something like this maybe

```
    let sessionData = [];

    register.find({
        'location.address': {
          $regex: '^' + req.body.address,
          $options: 'i'
        },
    //   }] typo
    }).exec(function (err, userDetail) {
        if (err) {
            // send error response
            return;
        }

        if (!userDetail || !userDetail.length) {
           // send empty response ?
           return res.json({
               code: 200,
               data: []
           });
       }

        async.eachSeries(userDetail, (user, callback) => {
            sessionSlot.findOne({
                'userID': user._id
            }).exec(function (err1, slotData) {

                if(slotData && slotData.sessions.length) {
                    slotData.sessions.forEach((slots) => {
                        if (req.body.date) {
                          if (moment(slots.date).isSame(moment(req.body.date), 'day')) {
                            sessionData.push({
                              time: slots.time,
                              status: slots.status,
                              slotID: slotData.slotID,
                            });
                          }
                        }
                        else {
                          sessionData.push({
                            time: slots.time,
                            status: slots.status,
                            slotID: slotData.slotID,
                          });
                        }

                        // slot count will get incremented no matter what happens, is that okay ?
                        slotCnt++;
                    });
                }
                else {
                        // DONT DO THIS because the sessionData is collection of results of all users so 
                        // we shouldn't be clearing that collection if one user fails to meet certain condition
                        // unless it is your requirement

                        // console.log('no slot created..',slotData);
                        // sessionData = [];
                }

                callback();
            });
        }, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                //send error
                return;
            }

            res.json({
                code: 200,
                data: sessionData
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Why there is no else part of slotData condition? In my current scenario, all users' entry not in sessionSlot collection. Let say In userDetail, am getting 3 list of users. Among these 3 users, only two of them have entry in that sessionSlot collection. So How to handle that 3rd user whose entry is not in sessionSlot collection?

Comment: Okay!!! I changed from simple for loop to async and other stuff too!!! And now it is working fine!! Thank you so much.. I really appreciate. So I can make  your answer as correct one..